# Difference between "the main (something)" and "a main (something)"

Tags: word-usage

Normally, the adjective "main" is used to mean "the most important", but can I also use it to mean "one of the most important" if preceded by an indefinite article?

For example:

> That area was **a** main marketplace in Rome. (one of the most important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't use the indefinite article "a" before the adjective main if you want to use it to mean "most important".  The correct sentence is:

That area was the main marketplace in Rome.

However, if there are more such marketplaces, you can say:

That area was one of the main marketplaces in Rome.

Comment: You could also say, "That area was a **major** marketplace in Rome," since _major_ means "important" without the superlative sense of _main_.

Comment: @CanadianYankee, Yes, we can.